# Installation of Software Center in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I have removed Software Center and now I am unable to install it.

Where can I get it and how can I install it?

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window, then issue command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. All need to be installed through terminal.

#### Gnome Software

This is what you have removed by mistake. To install it back, simply run:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

---

#### Ubuntu Software Center

This used to be the default GUI software manager. Still many, would prefer to have this instead of Gnome Software. Install it by:

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

---

#### Synaptic Package Manager

Many prefer this over the two mentioned earlier. Simply install it by:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```